# A proxy web service to a web service - where am I missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I program ASP.NET Framework MVC and Web API 2

I have to access a REST service for some information. The nature of the security requirements for this service require that I ask from a limited set of known IP addresses. The nature of my client requirements is that there will be an unknown number of them with IPs that are assigned by some DHCP. I think I need to stand up a proxy that will forward requests to the service and return responses to the client that asked. This server can be assigned a single static IP, that I can register with the target service. I don't want to try to duplicate the signatures of the target service and have to maintain my proxy whenever they decide to improve interfaces.

I would have the service that is restricting IPs and accepts a GET for http://S/action as an example. I would have the proxy at http://P/action. The client would send GET http://P/action and P would, in response, send GET http://S/action, collect the response, return it back to the client.

An attempt to implement this strategy, here is a handler I built for P that doesn't work:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        DelegatingHandler handler = new DelegatingHandlerProxy<ProxyHandler>();
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(handler);
    }
}
```

DelegatingProxyHandler is a way to get my dependency injection container involved:

```
public sealed class DelegatingHandlerProxy<THandler> : DelegatingHandler
    where THandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IDependencyScope scope = request.GetDependencyScope();
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> task;
        if (scope.GetService(typeof(THandler)) is DelegatingHandler handler)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(handler.InnerHandler, InnerHandler))
            {
                handler.InnerHandler = InnerHandler;
            }

            HttpMessageInvoker invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(handler);
            task = invoker.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Handler not registered with DI container");
        }

        return task;
    }
}
```

The ProxyHandler that I want to do the work is:

```
public class ProxyHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    public ProxyHandler(
        ITransformRequest preProcessor,
        ITransformResponse postProcessor,
        IForwardRequest forwarder)
    {
        PreProcessor = preProcessor;
        PostProcessor = postProcessor;
        Forwarder = forwarder;
    }

    private ITransformRequest PreProcessor { get; }
    private ITransformResponse PostProcessor { get; }
    private IForwardRequest Forwarder { get; }

    #region Overrides of DelegatingHandler

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        }

        if (PreProcessor != null)
        {
            request.RequestUri = PreProcessor.Transform(request.RequestUri);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = await Forwarder.Forward(request, cancellationToken);
        HttpResponseMessage transformedResponse = PostProcessor.Transform(response);
        return transformedResponse;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In this case, the DI container supplies a PreProcessor that changes host, port, and prefix of the request to the target service.  The Forwarder sends the request to the target using HttpClient.  The PostProcessor will be a noop.

I didn't build any controllers.  My thinking is that if this pipeline behaves as I expect, there won't be any controller that needs invoking.  When I send ant request to this, http://P/anything returns a 404, not htto://S/anything.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to **write** a proxy server when there are many free and ready built options available?

Comment: You already mentioned it in your question: `Web API` (even `MVC`  or bare bones). No other "components" needed to do what you want to do. It's no different from implementing any other _3rd party REST API_ that you want to offer "your" users - e.g. Paypal REST API

Comment: Writing a proxy is in m mind because I am a programmer and my first thought is to write something.  Maybe "implement a proxy" is a better phrase, so that it covers the "buy" option, as well as the "build" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular reason you're not just writing a set of matching controllers that accept client requests and then execute the equivalent request on the 3rd arty API using a service that implements a simple web client and then returning the responses - perhaps including some authentication & caching logic to lower the impact on their API?

If your 3rd party API provider is limiting requests by IP, that is likely because they trust (or explicitly require) you to manage requests to their API in order to protect it from excessive load and/or security risks. Directly forwarding all client requests without any logic in your middleware means you're negating this limitation.

If the *only* purpose of your application is to provide a static IP (and you do not need to add any logic in your code) then you should consider using one of the many off the shelf API gateway products - e.g. *Kong*, which is an open source and very well established with plenty of community support https://konghq.com/kong-community-edition/

Comment: 3rd party hasn't explicitly required me to limit loading their service.  They must be trusting me.

Comment: The clients that would call on this service are all products of my company.  Each of those clients would follow the security policies we have in place for our code, and would be part of the contract between me and 3rd party.  External agents would not send arbitrary requests to the servece.  I am not trying to be some sort of anonymzier.